# automapper error in C#.The best overloaded match for ..... has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using automapper for my `C#` project. I am using repository patterns. I am taking data as

```
var EmpData=EmployeeRepository.FindAll();
var EmployeeData=Mapper.Map<Company.Employee,HR.Employee>(EmpData);
```

I am getting an error saying

> The best overloaded match for ..... has some invalid arguments

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FindAll()` method return a collection of the data.

Here you are mapping it for single object. You have to map collection of objects.

Try

```
 var EmployeeData=Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Company.Employee>,IEnumerable<HR.Employee>>(EmpData);
```

or

```
var EmployeeData=Mapper.Map<ICollection<Company.Employee>,ICollection<HR.Employee>>(EmpData);
```